# FTP zip upload and unpack

Tags: upload, ftp

Hi Alsways uploading  made web-sites , projects, I want to make such thing

make zip file,
upload one file
and then extract with default CHMOD for folders lets say 755 and for files 664

With Cpanel hostings its OK, I can do it via file manager... But for hostings without I can't. 
Baybe someone can give a hint how...????

Comment: It sounds like you're not exactly asking for instructions on how to do this with FTP, but pointers on writing your own app to do this.

Could you tell us more about your platforms/languages of choice? There's a good chance something like this already exists

Comment: I think your keyboard is broken :)

Comment: I seek for a soulution, which already exists. 
Why it seems my keyboard is broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use php unzipper. Here is quick tutorial on it.

[Tutorial](http://zebida.com/main/how-to-extract-zip-files-on-ftp-server-using-php/)

Answer (score 1):

The FTP protocol doesn't allow for such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I keep a locked down directory where I drop compressed files and I have a little PHP script that unzips them by doing `glob("*.zip")` to get all the files, and executing the `unzip` on them.

My "solution" does require the ability to execute commands, but if you're in a more restricted environment you can use PHP's `zip_` functions or even a PEAR package.